# wrap text in maatwebsite is not working with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

I am trying to wraptext start from A1 but it's not working and throws an error getStyle method is not found

```
Excel::create('complaint_report', function ($excel) use ($compsArray) {
    // Set the spreadsheet title, creator, and description
    $excel->setTitle('complaints report');
    $excel->setCreator('Laravel')->setCompany('Beegains, LLC');
    $excel->setDescription('complaints file');

    // Build the spreadsheet, passing in the comps array
    $excel->sheet('sheet1', function ($sheet) use ($compsArray) {
        $sheet->fromArray($compsArray, null,getStyle('A1')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true), false, false);
    });
})->download('xlsx');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not calling the `getStyle` function on the sheet. Simply update to:

```
$sheet->fromArray($compsArray, null, 'A1', false, false)
    ->getStyle('A1')
    ->getAlignment()
    ->setWrapText(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

U can also use my method :

```
$sheet->fromArray([], null, 'A1', false, false)
->getStyle('A1')
->getAlignment()
->setWrapText(true);
```

**A1 = YOUR CELLS**

and this is the result :

[image]